# vim: how to change a few last letters of the word?

Tags: vim

Imagine you need to change a few last letters in a word.
From

```
.. visualizing a graph?_
```

(`_` denotes where the cursor is, mode:normal)

you need to arrive at

```
.. visualize| a graph?
```

(`|` denotes the cursor, mode:insert)

**How would you do this?**
(please suggest how would you *really* do this, not the "super-doper" way nobody uses)

I am asking, because I do this insanely inefficiently:
type `b` until reach `_visualizing a graph?`,
followed by `e` (`visualizinG a graph?`),
followed by `x` to remove `g` under cursor,
followed by few `Shift+x` to remove what is before the cursor,
and, finally, `i` switch into the insert mode and type `e`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With given example, I would do:

```
Tzcwe
```

Comment: and if you have `visualizing the zrun graph?_` (`z` is not unique)

Comment: @Ayrat I said with given example... if z is not uniq, press `;`, or try easymotion plugin.

Comment: @Ayrat `2Tzcwe` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

If there are just a few words between the cursor and where I want to go, I will use `CTRL+left` as many times as needed plus `CTRL+right` once and `<bs>` 3 times. I may also use the mouse. It's not that different from what you use, except I don't leave the insert mode for simple moves. Note this is exactly what I use when I type messages in my browser (I've never been conquered by vimperator & co).

I'm aware of `<esc>gegege`...`3<left>cwe<esc>`. But that's definitively not my first choice.

I may use `T` and `F` on symbols with few occurrences, but I seldom use them on letters as I'll spend more time detecting the best character to use than using CTRL+cursor as many times as needed. Beside, when I'm correcting what I've typed, it's likely that my mind is in "reread+correct/refactor sentences" mode, speed typing is not my priority.

Comment: typing cursor is too expensive with my keyboard, `Fn+[` is up `Fn+;` is left... and I really don't need cursors that much, except in browser's address bar...

Comment: I use `up` all the time in bash, gvim command mode, gdb history. And even in this exact edit-box to edit my comment.

Comment: In shell(zsh or bash) I have emacs binding, ctrl-p does your `up` does. also there are a lot short cut with ctrl/alt-... e.g. c-f c-w c-u c-k c-r c-h  a-w a-b ..... ctrl is used in sh extremely often here....